# How to create a Docusign envelope with a custom pdf (Python, Django)

Tags: python, django, pdf, docusignapi, weasyprint

My goal is to create a pdf using WeasyPrint and add it the the payload sent to the Docusign Api when requesting an envelope to be created.

Here are my steps:

1. generate the a pdf with WeasyPrint and return a based64 string

```
def generate_envelope_document(document_name: str, context: dict):
    content = render_to_string(f"insurance_contracts/{document_name}.html", 
    context=context)
    css = find(f"insurance_contracts/{document_name}.css")
    doc = HTML(string=content, media_type="screen").write_pdf(stylesheets=[css], 
    zoom=0.8)
    return base64.b64encode(doc).decode("utf-8")
```

2. create my envelope definition:

```
def create_envelope_definition(envelope_data: dict, context: dict, custom_fields: dict = None):
    mandate = Document(
        document_base64=generate_envelope_document("name1", context),
        name="name1",
        file_extension="pdf",
        document_id=1,
    )
    conditions = Document(
        document_base64=generate_envelope_document("name2", context),
        name="name2",
        file_extension="pdf",
        document_id=2,
    )
    signer = Signer(
        email=envelope_data["signer_email"],
        name=envelope_data["signer_name"],
        recipient_id="1",
        routing_order="1",
    )
    signer.tabs = Tabs(
        sign_here_tabs=[
            SignHere(
                anchor_string="Sign",
                anchor_units="pixels",
                anchor_y_offset="50",
                anchor_x_offset_metadata="50",
            )
        ]
    )

    envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
        status="sent", documents=[mandate, conditions], recipients=Recipients(signers=[signer])
    )

    if custom_fields:
        envelope_definition.custom_fields = CustomFields(
            text_custom_fields=[
                TextCustomField(name=field_name, value=field_value, required=False)
                for field_name, field_value in enumerate(custom_fields)
            ]
        )

    return envelope_definition
```

3. create a Docusign Api object:

```
def get_envelopes_api_client():
    """
    Create the docusign api client object
    Return  EnvelopesApi object
    """
    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.host = settings.DOCUSIGN_BASE_PATH
    api_client.set_default_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + get_access_token())
    envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)

    return envelope_api
```

4. create and send the Docusign envelope:

```
 envelope_api = get_envelopes_api_client()

    try:
        envelope = envelope_api.create_envelope(
            settings.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID, envelope_definition=envelope_definition
        )
    except ApiException as e:
        logger.error(e.body.decode())
        return None


    return envelope
```

at the moment I'm getting this error:

{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Could not cast or convert from System.String to API_REST.Models.v2_1.propertyMetadata."}

I don't understand what I could be doing wrong. Is my envelope definition not correct or is there something else I am missing. I can't seem to find official documentation on how to do this. All I have found is [https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/send-binary/][1] which does not use the docusign SDK.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `email_subject` needs to be added to `envelope_definition` and has some value. That's the subject of the email sent out by DocuSign.
- `document_id="2"` instead of `document_id=2`
- `anchor_x_offset_metadata` should not be used here and is probably the reason for your error.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. i will fix my integer instead of string error and add the email_subject field and then update my results. 

Comment: So i updated the envelope definition to include email_subject: `envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition( email_subject="contract",  documents=[mandate, conditions], recipients=Recipients(signers=[signer]), status="sent", )` and fixed the document_id value but i still get the same error response: `docusign.envelopes_api envelopes_api 484 140155845900096 {"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Could not cast or convert from System.String to API_REST.Models.v2_1.propertyMetadata."}` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What are the mandatory fields needed to be included in the envelope definition payload? 

Comment: Would it be helpful if i included my envelope definition payload here in the forum?

Comment: I propose a different approach, we have a working Python code example that you can try. Would you mind going to https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/master/app/eg001_embedded_signing/controller.py

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/  will also set up the code with all the configuration that is needed for you and get you working Python code.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll carefully compare  the code example to my code. By the way, do you know what the meaning of  **"Could not cast or convert from System.String to API_REST.Models.v2_1.propertyMetadata."** in the returned error message? 

Comment: This seems like a bug. can you tell me what version of the python package are you using?

Comment: We use Python 3.8 in our project. Thanks!

Comment: SOLVED: my problem was that in the **signer.tabs** class member there is a **SignHere** class with **anchor_y_offset** and **anchor_x_offset** members. I had set **anchor_y_offset="50"**, and then **anchor_x_offset_metadata="50"**, instead of setting **anchor_x_offset="50"**.  Could i suggest that Docusign send clearer error messages? For example in my project we check that all required fields are included in payloads sent to us. If we don't get everything we need we return an error with a message for each felid thats missing in the response.

Comment: aha, this is an interesting one, not an issue we run into before. I'll ask if we can improve the error message. I'll also update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And nice product! We use Docusign a lot in France.